# sending email in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin

I'm trying to send an email in my xamarin forms project, I have tried both in the iPhone simulator and on an iPhone device. When I push the send email button on the iPhone, nothing happens, not even a debug error. I have also made sure i am logged in with my email on the device.

I have used serviceDependency and followed the setup at this link:
https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/shared_resources/email/send_an_email/

my interface:

```
public interface InterfaceEmail
{
    void sendEmail();
}
```

iOS implementation:

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(SendEmail))]
namespace myProject.iOS
{
    public partial class SendEmail : InterfaceEmail
    {
        MFMailComposeViewController mailController;

        public SendEmail() {}
        public void sendEmail()
        {
            if (MFMailComposeViewController.CanSendMail)
            {

                mailController = new MFMailComposeViewController();

                mailController.SetToRecipients (new string[] {"my@email.com"});
                mailController.SetSubject ("test mail");
                mailController.SetMessageBody ("This is a test", false);

                mailController.Finished += (object sender, MFComposeResultEventArgs e) =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Result.ToString());
                    e.Controller.DismissViewController(true, null);
                };



                UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController.PresentViewController(mailController, true, null);
    }}}}
```

Implementation in my shared code:

```
async void Handle_ToolbarButton(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    var action = await DisplayActionSheet("What do you want to do?", "Abort", null, "Send email");
    if(action == "Send email")
    {
        DependencyService.Get<InterfaceEmail>().sendEmail();
    }
}
```

Does anyone have an idea on what could be wrong here?

Comment: here is https://youtu.be/JuJWwmO8Yq4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably it is related to this bug:
https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=58933

Just remove DisplayActionSheet.

Or if you want to use it, then there is a temporary solution in this Xamarin forum [topic](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/96707/gallary-not-showing-after-opening-display-sheet)
Add

```
await Task.Delay(100);
```

after DisplayActionSheet

Answer (score 7):

For a better way to send email without even writing platform specific code install this nuget into your solution
 xam.plugin.Messaging(https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xam.Plugins.Messaging/)

Then write the code below in PCL

```
var email = new EmailMessageBuilder()
  .To("to.plugins@xamarin.com")
  .Subject("Xamarin Messaging Plugin")
  .Body("Well hello there from Xam.Messaging.Plugin")
  .Build();
```

You can also add attachments. For more details please go through https://github.com/cjlotz/Xamarin.Plugins/blob/master/Messaging/Details.md

Comment: Super convenient. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 1):

The iPhone simulator will always return false to `CanSendMail` as it can not send mail. On a physical device, you will need to configure at least on e mail account.

Also:

Typo in:

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(sendEmail))]
```

Should be:

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(SendEmail))]
```

Typo in:

```
mailController.Finnished += ~~~~~
```

Should be:

```
mailController.Finished += ~~~~~
```

Comment: The typo's you pointed out is just in this post and should not be a problem in my code.
When I run in simulator the value of CanSendMail is set to true, but I have also tried with a physical device to be sure, but nothing happens on the iPhone when i push the send mail button. The debugger will go through each step of the code, but with no result.

Comment: `CanSendMail` should be false in the sim., are you running a older **beta** version of iOS? as this was broken in the iOS framework. Running an old version of `Xamarin.iOS`?

Comment: I am running the newest version of xamarin.iOS, and the reason that CanSendMail is true is because i am logged in with my email on the simulator. Is there anything else that could cause my problem?